# List view is not populating with database when first time activity start

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, listadapter

I am using SQlite Database.I create 2 tables and populate them(working fine) and use there data to show in list view. when first time  list adapter is populating list view show  newDATA varibale as zero. some data. but when i go back and furter start that activity newDATA has correct values. . I use below code

```
public ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> GetDataFirst(String id) {
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> firstvariable = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();



        Cursor c =sdb.rawQuery("Select * from table_name ",new String[]{id} );
        String[] colums = c.getColumnNames();



        while (c.moveToNext()) {
            HashMap<String, Object> record = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            for (int i = 0; i < colums.length; i++) {
                record.put(colums[i], c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(colums[i])));

            }

            {
              ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> now_add = GetmainData(id, record.get("vget").toString());
              record.put("NewDATA", now_add);

              hint.add(record);


            } 
            }       

        }
          c.close();
        return firstvariable ;
    }



public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> GetCluesDataVerical(String id,String vhid) {
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> hint = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        Cursor c = sdb.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM table_data", new String[] {id,vhid});
        String[] colums = c.getColumnNames();
        while (c.moveToNext()) {
            HashMap<String, String> record_add = new HashMap<String, String>();
            for (int i = 0; i < colums.length; i++) {
                record_add.put(colums[i], c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(colums[i])));
            }


            hint.add(record_add);
        }
          c.close();
        return hint;  
    }
```

and in list adapter i call these as below:

```
 recordData=context.crossDatabaseAdapter.GetDataFirst(value);

 wArray = (ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>) recordData.get(position).get("NewDATA");
```

I tried a lot But  still not come with any solution.

Answer (score 0):

You must use an instance state to save the content of the list adapter when you stop the application and when application is starting you must check if you can retrieve data thanks to instance state, else load data from database, this might solve your problem